# How to interpolate temperature from a set of data using metpy.interpolate

Tags: python, interpolation, metpy

I'm trying to generate a map using `cartopy` and `metpy.interpolate`, and I want the final products to be similar to this picture below [Image taken from NDAWN website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Q1Oy.png). I have a set of data with coordinate and temperature (lat, lon, temp):

> lat:  [49.8134, 49.8134, 49.8134, 49.8134, 49.8134, 49.8134, 49.8134,
> 49.8134, 49.8134, 49.8134]
>
> lon:  [-100.3721, -100.3721, -100.3721, -100.3721, -100.3721,
> -100.3721, -100.3721, -100.3721, -100.3721, -100.3721]
>
> tem:  [-8.45, -4.026, -5.993, -3.68, -7.35, -7.421, -6.477, -8.03,
> -3.834, -13.04]

I'm trying to interpolate the temperature and use `contourf` to draw it out. However, I have no idea how to interpolate them using `metpy's interpolation` function. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example. I had to change the lat/lon values from above since that is a single point only repeated above (which you can't interpo

```py
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import metpy.interpolate as minterp
from metpy.plots import StationPlot
import numpy as np

# Generate some locations for the data--originals were a single point
tem = np.array([-8.45, -4.026, -5.993, -3.68, -7.35, -7.421,
                -6.477, -8.03, -3.834, -13.04])
lat = 49 + np.random.rand(len(tem))
lon = -100 - np.random.rand(len(tem))

# Interpolating directly on the sphere with lat/lon is problematic
# so interpolate to a grid on a LambertConformal projection
proj = ccrs.LambertConformal(central_latitude=49, central_longitude=-100)
x, y, _ = proj.transform_points(ccrs.PlateCarree(), lon, lat).T

# Interpolate to a grid with 5km spacing
x_grid, y_grid, tem_grid = minterp.interpolate_to_grid(x, y, tem, interp_type='barnes',
                                                       hres=5000)

# Create figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=proj)

# Contourf plot
ax.contourf(x_grid, y_grid, tem_grid)

# Use MetPy's StationPlot to plot the text values
sp = StationPlot(ax, x, y, transform=proj, fontsize=16)
sp.plot_parameter('C', tem)

# Show grid locations
ax.scatter(x_grid, y_grid)
```

which yields:

[image: Sample image with filled contours and text plot]

For more information I'd suggest looking at [this example](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/examples/gridding/Wind_SLP_Interpolation.html) in the MetPy documentation.

EDIT: I'm transforming the coordinates from lat/lon in degrees because interpolating with degrees is problematic since the spacing isn't equal. So I transform to a projected coordinate system, which gives us an even spacing and I can request the grid spacing of 5km.

The use of `PlateCarree()` in the call to `transform_points()` is how you communicate to Cartopy that the coordinates being given are lon/lat coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes the coordinates were incorrect so I changed it. I have a few questions regarding this and I hope you can help me:

Q1: My coordinate is in longitude and latitude, and I read somewhere that hres therefore should be in degree (0.1, 0.2,... etc), but you use hres=5000 here and it works. Why is that ? And what is the general rule of thumb to choose hres?

Q2: I figured out that I have to transform coordinate from LambertConformal to PlateCarrer for interl=polation to work properly. What is the reason of this ?

Comment: I edited the answer above to clarify.